# React useState setters causing re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm wondering if it's expected behavior for the setter in: `const [state, setState] = useState(0)` to trigger component re-renders. So if I pass the setter to a component as a prop, is it supposed to trigger a re-render, and if so, why? Is there any way to avoid this?

I create a very simple sandbox to demonstrate the behavior: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-maxwell-qj5mi

Here we can see when viewing the `console.logs` that the button component gets re-rendered with each click, while the `incrementCounter` function passed into it isn't changing. What gives?

Comment: If you don't want to trigger a re-render use useRef or useMemo depending on the situation

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you [memoize](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) the button, you do not experience this behavior.

Specifically, this:

```js
const Button = memo(({ incrementCounter }) => {
  const renderCount = useRef(1);
  console.log("button rendered: ", renderCount.current);
  renderCount.current++;
  return <button onClick={incrementCounter}>Increment</button>;
});
```

CodeSandbox Mirror:

[image: Edit delicate-http-b6sym]

---

***Update***

If you wanted [something from the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) the first sentence will tell you why this is happening. I know thats for `setState` but the same concept follows the `useState` hook, but the docs for that kind of suck. [You can check out](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#recap) this part of the docs, specifically where it says "Line 9:"...

Remember, when state changes in X component, X component gets re-rendered, along with all of its children.  I know React tells you to "lift state up", which is something I have never understood, because lifting state up causes a crap load of re-renders.

That is why the button re-renders.. because state is changing in its parent. The parent (`<App />`) has it's `counter` state changed, which triggers the re-render of the `<App />` component, and its children, including `<Button />`.

In my opinion React is hard to control as far as state and re-renders, which Redux can assist with, but overall things like `memo`, `useCallback`, etc.. all feel like band-aids to me. If you put your state in the wrong component, you're going to have a bad time.

Wrapping the `<Button />` component [in `memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) basically says: if this component has a parent (in our case the `<App />`), and that parent re-renders, I want to look at all of our props, and if our props have not changed from what we received last time, don't re-render. Essentially, only re-render if our props change. That is why `memo` fixes this.. because the function we are using to handle the `incrementCounter` prop does not change - it remains constant.

I have added a few examples below demonstrating this.

---

***Original Answer/Snippet:***

```js
const { memo, useState, useCallback, useEffect, useRef } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const incrementCounter = useCallback(() => {
    setCounter(c => c + 1);
  }, [setCounter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("increment changed!");
  }, [incrementCounter]);

  return (
    <div>
      <CountValue counter={counter} />
      <Button incrementCounter={incrementCounter} />
    </div>
  );
}

const CountValue = ({ counter }) => {
  return <div>Count value: {counter}</div>;
};

const Button = memo(({ incrementCounter }) => {
  const renderCount = useRef(1);
  console.log("button rendered: ", renderCount.current);
  renderCount.current++;
  return <button onClick={incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
});

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

***SNIPPET #2:***

This snippet shows how everything, not just the button, gets re-rendered.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const App = () => {
  console.log("App rendered");
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const incrementCounter = () => setCounter(c => c + 1);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(" - Increment fired!");
    console.log();
  }, [incrementCounter]);

  return (
    <div>
      <CountValue counter={counter} />
      <Button incrementCounter={incrementCounter} />
      <p>Open console</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const CountValue = ({ counter }) => {
  console.log("CountValue rendered");
  return <div>Count value: {counter}</div>;
};

const Button = ({ incrementCounter }) => {
  console.log("Button rendered");
  return <button onClick={incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
};

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

***SNIPPET #3:***

This snippet shows how if you move state, etc.. into the `<CountValue />` component, the `<App />` component does not re-render..

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const App = () => {
  console.log("App rendered");
  
  return (
    <div>
      <CountValue />
      <p>Open console</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const CountValue = () => {
  console.log("CountValue rendered");
  
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const incrementCounter = () => setCounter(c => c + 1);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Count value: {counter}</div>
      <Button incrementCounter={incrementCounter} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Button = ({ incrementCounter }) => {
  console.log("Button rendered");
  console.log();
  return <button onClick={incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
};

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

***SNIPPET #4:***

This snippet is more of a thought experiment which shows how to use render props.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const App = () => {
  console.log("App rendered");

  return (
    <div>
      <CountValue present={({ increment, counter }) => {
        return (
          <div><Button incrementCounter={() => increment()} />
          <p>Counter Value: {counter}</p></div>
        )
      }} />
      <p>Open console</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const CountValue = ({ present }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  
  const increment = () => {
    setCounter(c => c + 1);
  }
  
  console.log("CountValue rendered");
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {present({ increment, counter })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const Button = ({ incrementCounter }) => {
  console.log("Button rendered");
  return <button onClick={incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
};

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

***SNIPPET #5:***

It seems like this is what you're after.. This only re-renders the CountValue.. This is accomplished by passing the `setCounter` method, which is produced by `useState`, up to the parent, via an callback object.

This way the parent can manipulate state, without having to actually hold the state.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const App = () => {
  console.log("App rendered");
  let increaseCount;

  return (
    <div>
      <CountValue callback={({increment}) => increaseCount = increment} />
      <Button incrementCounter={() => increaseCount()} />
      <p>Open console</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const CountValue = ({ callback }) => {
  console.log("CountValue rendered");
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  
  callback && callback({
    increment: () => setCounter(c => c + 1)
  });
  
  return <p>Counter Value: {counter}</p>;
};

const Button = ({ incrementCounter }) => {
  console.log("Button rendered");
  return <button onClick={incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
};

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great! I'll mark this as the answer, but I'm still curious as to why the setter triggers a re-render in the first place. Any idea of why this is? Or where I could read about it in the docs?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an explanation and some demos.. hopefully that helps!

Comment: @CaptainStiggz see my latest update, specifically ***SNIPPET #5***, as it shows how you can accomplish this with only the `CountValue` component re-rendering.

Comment: and why is meme() not per default already "integrated"? I don't get the idea that a child component should re-render even if its props did not change, right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is expected.

If you avoid the re-render you won't see the value that was set in the screen.

In case you want to create a value that you can change without triggering a re-render use `useRef`.

Comment: Hmm, I would expect that the value, `counter` would trigger a rerender on the `Counter` component, but the `setCounter` triggering a re-render on the `Button` component is unexpected. The value is changing, but I don't think the setter is. In other words, I'd expect the `Counter` component to re-render, and the `Button` component not to.

Comment: If you look towards the top of the sandbox, I have a custom hook `useStaticState`, which is commented out. That wraps the setter in a `useRef`, but still triggers re-renders on the `Button` component, which was VERY surprising to me.

Comment: @CaptainStiggz when a React component re-renders, *all* of it children re-render by default